# Should we do something special when we hit our 2000th question?

Tags: discussion

We're currently at 1905 as of me asking this, so the 2K question is coming up.

Could we do something special? like maybe a special gift to the asker of that question?

I dunno, I thought it would be nice and sort of celebratory of getting this far and graduating.

**EDIT:** So, unless a question gets deleted, our 2000th question is

[Identify book about fighting tournament with the opponent wearing gold armor, plus rulers being mind-controlled by tentacled being](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/8499/1109)

and 2001st

[Was the lower half of Robocop's face vulnerable (to gunfire)?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/8505/1109)

Comment: Did we do anything special for the 1000th question?

Comment: I dunno. I wasn't here lol

Comment: Isn't it kind of hard to tell exactly which question is the 2000th? What with deletions and such?

Comment: @Martha We could just count the posts and then after a day or two when the threshold is reached, we would award the 2000th questioner or something. I dunno, I thought it could be fun.

Comment: @Martha Best not to count deleted questions (there are >300 of them).

Comment: Given that this is Sci-Fi, we should probably wait until [2001](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2579/what-is-the-end-of-2001-a-space-odyssey-about).

Comment: We should answer the 2000th question

Comment: How can you tell which question number we're at?

Comment: @Wikis [Question Count](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions)

Comment: Ah, it's so obvious! Thx.

Comment: Someone please delete *just one* closed question. I want to say I answered the 2000th question. ;)

Answer (score 4):

Surely we should celebrate the 2013th question, when the future is now. Treating 2000 as the future is so passé.

The problem with selecting a number like this is that it's easy to know when the question is coming up and force the issue. There should be an element of uncertainty.

We've practically hit the 2000th non-deleted question. I suspect there are a few closed questions that need deleting. How about: we wait until the 2030th question or so, then moderators go and do the periodic cleanup of old closed questions, then we see exactly which question to declare 2013th?

Not that I have any idea what to do to celebrate.

---

As of today, non-deleted questions #2000 and #2013 are:

- [Revelation Space - Why didn't the ship get trashed when Volyova put it into reverse?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/8603/revelation-space-why-didnt-the-ship-get-trashed-when-volyova-put-it-into-reve)
- [Why do the Weasleys have to de-gnome the garden at the Burrow?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/8646/why-do-the-weasleys-have-to-de-gnome-the-garden-at-the-burrow)